# how to enable/disable tab in Javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

How to enable tab when default is disabled in fxml?

```
... some code ...
 <TabPane fx:id="tabpan"  prefHeight="256.0" prefWidth="497.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
 <Tab id="shoppingltab" disable="true" text="Lists">
...
```

in controller I did make

```
@FXML private TabPane tabpan;
```

but i've got no idea how to enable this tab...

thx for help in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inject the tab into the controller (as you do with the tab pane):

```xml
<Tab fx:id = "shoppingltab" ... >
```

and in the controller

```
@FXML private Tab shoppingltab;
```

Then you can enable the tab in the controller with

```
shoppingltab.setDisable(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the setDisable method on any tab that is bind to the controller